# Trigger horas cada 30 m en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Soy nuevo en **sql** y no se cómo abordar este problema.

Tengo una **tabla** que almacena **citas** con un `atributo hora` del tipo *varchar2*.
Necesito un **trigger** que *evite* la *inserción y actualización* de horas que no sean en punto o a y media, es decir que solo haya citas cada media hora.
No tengo idea de cómo hacerlo, espero pudieran ayudarme.
Gracias

Comment: Como haces las inserciones? eso parece mas una regla de negocios que una regla que pertenezca a la base de datos.. Si el campo es varchar.. recibes un string? y si se rechaza la hora... como lo vas a avisar?

Comment: Es que es un trabajo para clase, la idea es crear una base de datos para una clínica. La clínica tiene la regla de negocio que las citas tienen que ser cada media hora por lo que quería almacenar las horas  en la base de datos para más tarde hacer una web de petición de citas para los clientes en la que se le desplieguen todas las citas disponibles

Comment: y los datos se cargan directamente en la base de datos? sin un sistema por delante?

Comment: Sí, es una asignatura en la que no explican mucho sobre el trabajo, un ejemplo era el de una bibilioteca tenia los libros en la base de datos y los usuarios podían pedir el préstamo de un libro. Mi idea era que las citas estuviesen ya prefijadas en la base de datos de manera que el cliente elija un día y un médico y se le desplieguen las horas disponibles para elegir.(Todo esto sería una vez la base de datos estuviera hecha)

Comment: eso se puede hacer tranquilamente y no estaria mal.. con una tabla de horarios disponibles.. pero devuelta, lo selecciona en la DB?

Comment: Perdón pero no he detallado suficiente, las horas de las citas disponibles las tiene que introducir un usuario "Recepcionista", luego mi idea pensando en la futura web que respaldará la DB era que esas citas válidas sean escogidas por los pacientes. No he creado previamente una tabla con las horas por lo que si se pudiera hacer con trigger sería mejor para mi

Comment: si las horas con las posibles citas las ingresa un recepcionista.. que impide que las turnos para un doc sean 00 y 30.. y para otro 15 y 45???

Comment: Vamos a ver, la clínica tiene un horario de trabajo de 9:00 a 14:00 y quiero que las citas sean cada media hora o cada cuarto y dentro de ese horario ,es un ejemplo. Por eso quiero un trigger que restrinja esas opciones de insertar las horas.

Comment: ok. en la respuesta que tienes tenes un ejemplo valido. Para mi tienes otros problemas mas abajo de este, pero eso por lo menos va a resolver esto.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer la validación de la siguiente manera.

Para las pruebas cree una tabla:

```
-- Create table
create table TIME_TEST
(
  HORA DATE
);
```

Luego cree el siguiente trigger que hace uso del EXTRACT para poder obtener el minuto de la hora en formato numérico:

```
create or replace trigger hora_tests
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON time_test
   REFERENCING OLD AS O
   NEW AS N
   FOR EACH ROW

declare
begin
   IF EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(:N.HORA as TIMESTAMP)) NOT IN (0,30) THEN
      Raise_Application_Error (-20343, 'Debe ser en punto o y media.');
   END IF;
end hora_tests;
```

Pruebas de funcionamiento de la validación:

```
SQL> insert into time_test values(to_date('01/08/2017 12:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'));

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into time_test values(to_date('01/08/2017 12:01', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'));

insert into time_test values(to_date('01/08/2017 12:01', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'))

ORA-20343: Debe ser en punto o y media.
ORA-06512: en "HORA_TESTS", línea 4
ORA-04088: error durante la ejecución del disparador 'HORA_TESTS'

SQL> insert into time_test values(to_date('01/08/2017 12:30', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'));

1 row inserted

SQL>
```

La otra forma, algo más simple, es verificar mediante un `CONSTRAINT` de tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo
(
  Hora DATE,
  CHECK (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(Hora as TIMESTAMP)) IN (0,30))
);
```

Al hacer esto:

```
  INSERT INTO Ejemplo(Hora)
  VALUES (to_date('01/08/2017 12:01', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'));
```

El error será algo así:

> ORA-02290: check constraint (USER_4_AB04F.SYS_C007366) violated

Comment: Aunque una solucion correcta, OP tiene la hora en un varchar2, y no aclara el formato. Esperemos a ver que dice, hay que ver con que formato le llega la misma.

Comment: Es verdad, si aclara el formato se puede convertir.

Comment: @Blasito, espero no te moleste, le agregué a tu respuesta el uso de `CONSTRAINTS`. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, no es molestia, la opción que agregaste es muy interesante y con eso el OP tiene otra alternativa para probar. Gracias por la edición. Saludos!

Comment: Faltaría validar que los segundos sean 0, ya que con la validación actual, el sistema aceptaría una cita hoy a las 15:30:25. Eso puede o no ser aceptable, pero supongo que el OP quiere que pueda ser solamente las 15:00:00 o las 15:30:00. Un saludo.